# How to use AJAX with IE8

Tags: ajax

can anyone of you tell me how to use ajax with IE8? (ActiveXObject) is not working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 supports the [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) object. You can use that to do ajax. The page also has an example:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.onreadystatechange = handler;
client.open("GET", "unicorn.xml");
client.send();
```